# Views Exposed Filters AND result for multi select field

Tags: views

I'm working with a view with exposed filters for a directory style page.

One of the filters is a multi-select check list, however, we want the results to return AND results only. It is currently returning OR.

For example: Activity open to:
- Men 
- Women
- Older People
- Children

So I only want to see results that have both selected.

All the testing I've done returns OR options, so they can have Men OR Women. I want Men AND Women returned.

Answer (score 0):

Views' filters default to an OR between all the options selected. If you pick the "Is all of" option, it will change to an AND operator.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the query as you like before executing it using [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x).